# Random Hard Lockups, Low CPU/RAM Usage on Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, 64-bit, 19.10, nvidia-geforce, amd-processor

System Specs:

- Proc: AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core 4000 Mhz
- MB: Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3 (rev 4.0)
- BIOS: F3 UEFI
- RAM: 16 GB (4+4+8)
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 630
- OS: Dual boot Kubuntu 19.10 (x64)/Windows 10 (x64)

Problem:
Kubuntu hard locks randomly even when idle with low RAM and CPU usage. I believe it's a hardware fault but Windows can run for months on end without any errors while Kubuntu will lockup in less than 24 hours. (When updates allow) No messages on dmesg when constantly monitoring through lockup, TTY, SSH, and REISUB all non-responsive. I attempted downgrading to 19.04 and 18.10 with the same problems. I am looking for farther troubleshooting steps to find the cause of my issue.

Updates:
Ran MemTest86 Free and all tests passed when running on core 0. But refused to start on cores 1 and 2, then stopped testing thinking it was dead cores on the proc. and I did notice that MemTest86 had a comment about this "BIOS" (UEFI) having a known issue with multi-core processing. After that I went back into Kubuntu and set the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu${corenum}/online`to `0` for all but core 0, and still experienced a hard freeze when running single-core mode. Any farther troubleshooting tips?

Comment: You have run a memtest? a cap-check  Windows and GNU/Linux allocate memory from opposite ends of your address range, so it'll come across the fault at very different times...  19.04 & 18.10 are both EOL thus off-topic

Comment: Just mentioned older builds as it's not exclusive to 19.10.